# Is there a TestNG annotation that start running before the class constructor just like JUnit @BeforeAll does?

Tags: java, junit, annotations, automated-tests, testng

The JUnit @BeforeAll tests are executed before the constructor and the declared class variables (as they should).

The TestNG @BeforeClass calls first the class constructor and classes variables before it runs itself.

Is there a TestNG annotation that starts to run BEFORE the class constructor is called,
just like JUnit @BeforeAll does?

I run a test with both TestNG @BeforeClass and JUnit @BeforeAll and they both give different responses.

JUnit example:

```
package Junit;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import pages.MyClass;

public class TestJunit {

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp(){
        System.out.println("1 - @BeforeAll Junit");
    }

    private MyClass str = new MyClass();

    public TestJunit() {
        System.out.println("3 - Junit Class Constructor");
    }

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        System.out.println("4 - Starting Junit Tests");
    }

}
```

- TestJunit - Junit Response:

1. @BeforeAll Junit
2. My Custom Class Constructor
3. Junit Class Constructor
4. Starting Junit Tests

TestNG example:

```
package TestNG;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import pages.MyClass;

public class TestTestNG {

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUp(){
        System.out.println("1 - BeforeAll TestNG");
    }

    private MyClass str = new MyClass();

    public TestTestNG() {
        System.out.println("3 - TestNG Class Constructor");
    }

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        System.out.println("4 - Starting TestNG Tests");
    }

}
```

- TestTestNG - TestNG Response:

2. My Custom Class Constructor
3. TestNG Class Constructor
4. BeforeAll TestNG
5. Starting TestNG Tests

My Custom Class:

```
package pages;

public class MyClass {

    public MyClass() {
        System.out.println("2 - My Custom Class Constructor");
    }
}
```

I want a TestNG solution (because @BeforeClass is not working) that will give the same response as the JUnit (@BeforeAll) solution.

Is there a TestNG annotation that starts to run BEFORE the class constructor is called,
just like JUnit @BeforeAll does?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You can use the @BeforeTest or the top level @BeforeSuite annotations to use as a "BeforeAll" alternative. Both of the will run before the test class constructors.
Following is the TestNG annotation execution order so you get the idea.

[image: TestNG hierarchy]

Comment: Just tested the code here with TestNG \@BeforeTest and \@BeforeSuite,
and both  also don't tun before the class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find a The TestNG annotation (@BeforeClass won't work) that works just like JUnit @BeforeAll (that executes even before the class constructor).

The best workaround I could find is to setup my code inside the class constructor itself, that's it.

PS: Maybe this is happening because TestNG tests can't be static while JUnit can.